# $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^2-4)(x^2-9)}\,\text dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, partial-fractions

I am trying to compute the following contour integration but am quite stuck I have to evaluate it analytically, by extending it to the complex plane and solving an appropriate integral involving a complex variable $z= x + iy$:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^2-4)(x^2-9)}\,\text dx$$

Comment: What does the foggy rectangle symbol mean?

Comment: @Nishant: i'm going to go with a guess that it is a mistaken character that doesn't need to be there and hope that the OP will double-check to make sure that the resulting edit is correct...

Comment: The integral is divergent.  If there was a symbol there, maybe it was meant to convey that.

Comment: Are you sure the denominator is not $(x^2+4)(x^2+9)$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

W/O using Complex Calculus,

$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2-4)(x^2-9)}=\frac15\cdot\frac{9(x^2-4)-4(x^2-9)}{(x^2-4)(x^2-9)}=\cdots$$

Now use [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ9/integ9.html)

Comment: You do realize that the integral is divergent, right...?

Answer (score 1):

by using the partial fraction 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^2}{(x^2-4)(x^2-9)}dx=(\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{5(x-2)}-\frac{1}{5(x-2)}+\frac{3}{10(x-3)}-\frac{3}{10(x+3)})dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{5}\log(\frac{x-2}{x+2})+\frac{3}{10}\log(\frac{x+3}{x-3})
$$
take the limit when $x=\infty$ to get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\log(\frac{x-2}{x+2})=0$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\log(\frac{x+3}{x-3})=0$$

$$I=-\frac{1}{5}\log(-1)-\frac{3}{10}\log(-1)=-\frac{i\pi }{2}$$

Comment: How does it make sense to get a complex number out of a limit of sums of real numbers...? Even the Cauchy PV will never do this. You have picked the wrong branch cuts.

Comment: I used a direct substitute of the boundary in the integral

Comment: What about the poles on the axis?  Any thought as to why you think the Fundamental theorem of Calculus applies there?